# Wordpress Plugin: OSCommerce images not displaying in front end

Tags: plugin-development

The below code is wordpress custom plugin code. I am trying the code from below link:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-wordpress-plugin-from-scratch--net-2668

```
    <?php
    if($_POST['oscimp_hidden'] == 'Y') {
        //Form data sent
        $dbhost = $_POST['oscimp_dbhost'];
        update_option('oscimp_dbhost', $dbhost);

        $dbname = $_POST['oscimp_dbname'];
        update_option('oscimp_dbname', $dbname);

        $dbuser = $_POST['oscimp_dbuser'];
        update_option('oscimp_dbuser', $dbuser);

        $dbpwd = $_POST['oscimp_dbpwd'];
        update_option('oscimp_dbpwd', $dbpwd);

        $prod_img_folder = $_POST['oscimp_prod_img_folder'];
        update_option('oscimp_prod_img_folder', $prod_img_folder);

        $store_url = $_POST['oscimp_store_url'];
        update_option('oscimp_store_url', $store_url);
        ?>
        <div class="updated"><p><strong><?php _e('Options saved.' ); ?></strong></p></div>
        <?php
    } else {
        //Normal page display
        $dbhost = get_option('oscimp_dbhost');
        $dbname = get_option('oscimp_dbname');
        $dbuser = get_option('oscimp_dbuser');
        $dbpwd = get_option('oscimp_dbpwd');
        $prod_img_folder = get_option('oscimp_prod_img_folder');
        $store_url = get_option('oscimp_store_url');
    }
?>
<div class="wrap">
    <?php    echo "<h2>" . __( 'OSCommerce Product Display Options', 'oscimp_trdom' ) . "</h2>"; ?>

         <form name="oscimp_form" method="post" action="<?php echo str_replace( '%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="oscimp_hidden" value="Y">
        <?php    echo "<h4>" . __( 'OSCommerce Database Settings', 'oscimp_trdom' ) . "</h4>"; ?>
        <p><?php _e("Database host: " ); ?><input type="text" name="oscimp_dbhost" value="<?php echo $dbhost; ?>" size="20"><?php _e(" ex: localhost" ); ?></p>
        <p><?php _e("Database name: " ); ?><input type="text" name="oscimp_dbname" value="<?php echo $dbname; ?>" size="20"><?php _e(" ex: oscommerce_shop" ); ?></p>
        <p><?php _e("Database user: " ); ?><input type="text" name="oscimp_dbuser" value="<?php echo $dbuser; ?>" size="20"><?php _e(" ex: root" ); ?></p>
        <p><?php _e("Database password: " ); ?><input type="text" name="oscimp_dbpwd" value="<?php echo $dbpwd; ?>" size="20"><?php _e(" ex: secretpassword" ); ?></p>
        <hr />
        <?php    echo "<h4>" . __( 'OSCommerce Store Settings', 'oscimp_trdom' ) . "</h4>"; ?>
        <p><?php _e("Store URL: " ); ?><input type="text" name="oscimp_store_url" value="<?php echo $store_url; ?>" size="20"><?php _e(" ex: http://www.yourstore.com/" ); ?></p>
        <p><?php _e("Product image folder: " ); ?><input type="text" name="oscimp_prod_img_folder" value="<?php echo $prod_img_folder; ?>" size="20"><?php _e(" ex: http://www.yourstore.com/images/" ); ?></p>

        <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="<?php _e('Update Options', 'oscimp_trdom' ) ?>" />
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

the config file data are given as:
database host: localhost
database name:osc234
database user:root
password: password
OSCommerce store settings

Stroe URL: http://localhost:8383/osc-234/catalog/index.php
product image folder: http://localhost:8383/osc-234/catalog/images

The template sidebar.php code I placed the below code

But I am not sure that I have placed in correct place. The images are not appeared in front end.

my sidebar.php is now looks like this:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Sidebar containing the main widget area
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Eleven
 * @since Twenty Eleven 1.0
 */

$options = twentyeleven_get_theme_options();
$current_layout = $options['theme_layout'];

if ( 'content' != $current_layout ) :
?>
        <div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
            <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) : ?>

                <aside id="archives" class="widget">
                    <h3 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Archives', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h3>
                    <ul>
                        <?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly' ) ); ?>
                    </ul>
                </aside>

                <aside id="meta" class="widget">
                    <h3 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Meta', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h3>
                    <ul>
                        <?php wp_register(); ?>
                        <li><?php wp_loginout(); ?></li>
                        <li><?php echo oscimp_getproducts(3); ?></li>
                        <?php wp_meta(); ?>
                    </ul>
                </aside>

            <?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?>
        </div><!-- #secondary .widget-area -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You'll need to format the `<li>` line as code or it won't display here. The first block of code is in the right place if it works from the admin site (and it really ought to have some role checks in place I think - `current_user_can()` - at the moment any back-office user with the URL can break your osci database settings. I assume you've put  `oscimp_getproducts` in your plugin functions.php? (Which is pretty horrible, BTW, particularly the way it finds random products by guessing database IDs!! An `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $product_cnt` would be much better.) Any PHP errors in your server logs?

Comment: Actually reading up on ORDER BY RAND() that's not necessarily a good idea either :-/ if you have a huge table of products. There are [some suggestions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823306/mysql-alternatives-to-order-by-rand) but I'm not sure I like them either. Depending on how large your product table is you should either get (and cache!) the highest product ID and the row count, then guess lots of IDs at once in a single select using `IN` and a list of IDs - enough that you'd expect to get twice as many as you need based on the limit and how many IDs are populated ...

Comment: then repeat as necessary to get up to the required number if you don't get enough products in the first guess. You can do that as a single SELECT on the products table to return both ID and the image URL, then you just need a SELECT against the description table to return name, i.e. you should expect to use two queries total or maybe three or four in the worst case, and cover all products in the system not just IDs less than 30. Or if the table is small fetch and cache all valid product IDs and just select from that list: again two queries for image URL and name,

Comment: Thanks for the help. The eoscommerce_importer class already tries to retrieve fields from products table.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. The oscommer_importer.php file already tried to retrieve fields from products table. Here I have attached it.

`

```
<?php 
    /*
    Plugin Name: OSCommerce Product Display
    Plugin URI: http://localhost:8383
    Description: Plugin for displaying products from an OSCommerce shopping cart database
    Author: Priya Mohan
    Version: 1.0

    */

    function oscimp_admin() {
    include('oscommerce_import_admin.php');?>



<?php
}


    function oscimp_admin_actions() {
    add_options_page("OSCommerce Product Display", "OSCommerce Product Display", 1, "OSCommerce Product Display", "oscimp_admin");
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'oscimp_admin_actions');


function oscimp_getproducts($product_cnt=1) {
    //Connect to the OSCommerce database
    $oscommercedb = new wpdb(get_option('oscimp_dbuser'),get_option('oscimp_dbpwd'), get_option('oscimp_dbname'), get_option('oscimp_dbhost'));

    $retval = '';
    for ($i=0; $i<$product_cnt; $i++) {
        //Get a random product
        $product_count = 0;
        while ($product_count == 0) {
            $product_id = rand(0,30);
            $product_count = $oscommercedb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products WHERE products_id=$product_id AND products_status=1");
        }

        //Get product image, name and URL
        $product_image = $oscommercedb->get_var("SELECT products_image FROM products WHERE products_id=$product_id");
        $product_name = $oscommercedb->get_var("SELECT products_name FROM products_description WHERE products_id=$product_id");
        $store_url = get_option('oscimp_store_url');
        $image_folder = get_option('oscimp_prod_img_folder');

        //Build the HTML code
        $retval .= '<div class="oscimp_product">';
        $retval .= '<a href="'. $store_url . 'product_info.php?products_id=' . $product_id . '"><img src="' . $image_folder . $product_image . '" /></a><br />';
        $retval .= '<a href="'. $store_url . 'product_info.php?products_id=' . $product_id . '">' . $product_name . '</a>';
        $retval .= '</div>';

    }
    return $retval;
}
?>
```

`
I checked the log file and there is no php error.
I somewhat feel like store url and product image url are given wrong.

Store URL: [http://localhost:8383/wordpress/][1]

product image folder: 
[http://localhost:8383/osc-234/catalog/images/][1]

There is some point when I tried store url and product image folder with some other links, it displayed the X in place of image. (the image not displayed but the symbol like X got displayed) please help